# load module in requirejs only in browser, not in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I wrote modules for both browser and nodejs using requirejs.

Everything works fine, but I want to include a module just for the browser, not for node as I don't need it and it would not work in node. (It's just a fancy design library for the browser).

My code looks like this:

```
define([
    'requirement',
    'libs/fancy'
], function(Requirement, fancy) {
    // do stuff
});
```

fancy is the lib that I don't want in node. So I could write a workaround like this:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { // cheap detection of browser/node
    define([
        'requirement',
        'libs/fancy'
    ], start);
} else {
    define([
        'requirement'
    ], start);
}

function start(Requirement, Fancy) {
    // do stuff
}
```

But obviously this is ugly. Does anyone know a better way to do it?

-- EDIT 1:

```
var requirements = ['requirement'];

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    requirement.push('libs/fancy');
}

define(requirements, function(Requirement, Fancy) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Still not perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sometimes used the second method you show of creating an array of dependencies on which I push depending on what I need.

There's another method, however, that I've used when I don't want to modify the list of dependencies. Presumably the code inside your module will have to work with an `undefined` value for `Fancy`. So you could use something like what follows. The idea is to configure RequireJS to load a module that returns an `undefined` value when loaded. This way you don't need to modify your dependency list. It just needs to be able to handle a case where `Fancy` is undefined.

```
var requirejs = require("requirejs");

// Create a fake module that we name immediately as "undefined".
requirejs.define("undefined", [], function () { return undefined; });

var req = requirejs.config({
    map: {
        // Make it so that all requests for `foo` load `undefined` instead.
        "*": {
            foo: "undefined"
        }
    }
});

req(["foo"], function (foo) {
    console.log(foo);
});
```

The example above maps `foo` to `undefined` so when `console.log` executes, the value on the console is `undefined`. In your own code you'd map `libs/fancy` to `undefined`.

A variation on this method would be to have the `undefined` module return an object which shows the same interface as the real library but does nothing. This would avoid having to test whether `Fancy` is defined or not inside your module. I'd call the fake module something else than `undefined` though. Maybe something like `fake-fancy`.